# How to render a dynamic framer motion "motion tag" in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

I have a react typescript component that render a dynamic html tag like so:

```
import { type ElementType, type HTMLAttributes } from 'react';

interface IconButtonProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
   as?: ElementType;
}

const IconButton = ({ as, children, ...restProps }: IconButtonProps) => {
    const Tag = as ?? 'button';

    return (
        <Tag className="block rounded-full p-2" {...restProps}>
            {children}
        </Tag>
    );
};

export default IconButton;
```

That works fine, however, I need to render a dynamic `motion tag` (e.g motion.div, motion.button, etc, but render them dynamically based on an `as` prop)

i had tried something like this:

```
import { type ElementType, type HTMLAttributes } from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion'

interface IconButtonProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
    as?: ElementType;
}

const IconButton = ({ as, children, ...restProps }: IconButtonProps) => {
    const Tag = as ? motion[as] : motion.button; // the error happen in this line, to be exact motion[as]

    return (
        <Tag className="block rounded-full p-2" {...restProps}>
            {children}
        </Tag>
    );
};

export default IconButton;
```

and motion[as] method threw an error that says:
[image: error message]

Here's the desired result:

- Make the `Tag` variable return a `motion tag`
- Get rid of the error

Comment: I'm running your code and it has no error, 
here is what I tried : https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-mayer-5y9pjg?file=/src/Component.tsx

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh I've looked into your sandbox and still found the error at `motion[as]`, there's also an error occurred at the `ElementType` import.

Comment: aha got it ....

Answer (score 0):

it's probebly from ElementType if you change it to keyof ReactHtml your issue will be solved

```
import React, { ReactHTML, HTMLAttributes } from "react";

interface IconButtonProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
  as?: keyof ReactHTML;
}




const Tag = motion.custom(as ?? "button") as React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<
    MotionProps &
      React.RefAttributes<Element> & {
        children: React.ReactNode;
        className: string;
      }
  >;

// or you can use it in this way
// const Tag = motion.custom<any>(as ?? "button");
```

and here is codesandbox for it https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-mayer-5y9pjg?file=/src/Component.tsx

Comment: Yes, that's removed the error from the `motion[as]`, however, a new error has occurred from the `Tag` when you used it as an HTML tag (take a look at line 30) in the Component.tsx file

Comment: actually that was another issue, I fixed that in codesandbox